# How to set product to 0 if its a product over an empty list in Julia?

Tags: list, iterator, julia, product, empty-list

In my code I use Julia's prod() function to do a product over the elements of a list. However, sometimes that list is empty, in which case I want prod(myList) to just return 0 (or any fixed number like 1). I tried searching online, but the only things I could find were for iterators or stuff like that.

I'm using Julia version 1.5.2.

Comment: What does `eltype(MyList)` give when that list is empty? As mentioned in the comments, I think `prod` is the right function to use without modification and that the real issue may be  how you create that empty list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would a simple ternary operator work for your case?

```
isempty(my_list) ? 0 : prod(my_list)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution is type-unstable. If `my_list` is a vector of floats or complex numbers, the compiler cannot tell what type will be returned.

Comment: At least you could use `zero(my_list)` instead of 0 (Int64).

Comment: if `one(my_list)` worked then `prod(my_list)` would work, e.g. `prod(Int[])` is `1`. If `prod` fails it means that `eltype` of `my_list` is not defined or e.g. `Any` (most likely case).

Comment: I agree with DNF. And Bogumil, although I think in reply to crstnbr he meant `zero(my_list)` will fail if `prod(my_list)` was failing. I'd recommend using the Base `prod` function and just making sure that the list has a concrete `eltype` for which `one` works (E.g., `Int`, `Float64`, etc., will work, but certainly not `Any`).

Answer (score 3):

What you want is incorrect/unconventional. The [product of the elements of an empty sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) should be 1, because that is the multiplicative identity element.

Comment: No, in this case I want it to be 0. If you know how to make it 1 though that works because then I can just subtract 1.

Comment: So why not just define your own `prod` (＠_＠;)

Comment: Because I would like to have a clean way to do this, and why reinvent the wheel if its already done.

Comment: The product of an empty sequence being 1 means that we can take, say { 1, 2, 3 } and divide it into all possible subsequences, such that their individual products are all 6, including the empty sequences for instance prod({}) x prod({1, 2}) x prod({3}) is still 6.

Answer (score 1):

"Any fixed number" is easy:

```
reduce(*, ls; init=1)
```

But this does not work well with zero, since that is an annihilator and sends the whole product to zero:

```
julia> ls = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> reduce(*, ls; init=0)
0
```

Now, returning `1` and then checking for that works if you only have integers.  It doesn't as soon as you have a product over rationals, since then the resulting `1` could also stem from `x * (1/x)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
julia> zeroprod(x) = isempty(x) ? zero(eltype(x)) : prod(x)
zeroprod (generic function with 1 method)
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.